# VB.Net Multi-Threaded File Download

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I have a winform application written in VB.Net that needs to download XML files containing PubMed (medical journals) article data. I request data for 500 articles at a time because I need to stream it, and I want to avoid loading a file that would exceed available memory. In the returned file, the data for each article is contained in the `<PubmedArticle>` element:

```
<PubmedArticleSet>
    <PubmedArticle>
    ... (Article Data) ...
    </PubmedArticle>
    <PubmedArticle>
    ... (Article Data) ...
    </PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

My code looks something like this (the actual code executes the code below in a loop on 500 Pubmed IDs per iteration):

```
Dim pubmedIDs As String() = {"20816578", "20815951"}
Dim xmlUrl As String = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=", String.Join(",", pubmedIDs), "&retmode=xml&rettype=abstract")
Dim request as HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(xmlUrl), HttpWebRequest)
Try
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(responseStream)
            'Break up the requested file into one file per article and save them to a cache directory
            'Update a progress bar as files are cached
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As WebException
    'Handle HTTP errors by capturing Pubmed IDs of failed request to allow user to retry later
    'Update progress bar despite failed request to let user know when the process is finished
End Try
```

This all works fine, but on a typical run, I need to collect article data for 20K+ files, which takes about 10 minutes. Can someone give me advice on how I would go about multi-threading the requests?

Comment: The first trick will be to work out whether there'll be any benefit in multi-threading.  Your bottleneck is likely to be network bandwidth: downloading two files at once might just result in each file taking twice as long, so you may not save any time.

Comment: Does the code you provided load 2 based on pubmedIDs?  How big are the individual files?  Are you writing the files locally?  Multiple threads will probably speed this up as you will likely be waiting on IO.  At some point you will have a network bottleneck.

Comment: Good point, @DanPuzey. I looked at the size of the returned files more carefully. If I request data for 500 Pubmed IDs, the size of the file will be approximately 5MB. Therefore, I don't think network bandwidth would cause a bottleneck, but your comment made me consider whether I'm being too conservative about memory constraints. I tried upping the request to 1000 Pubmed IDs, which gave me a 414 error (URL too long), but 900 works! The execution time reduced by about 30%. I'd like it to be faster, but I think this is a good start. Thanks!

Comment: @dbasnett, yes, the example I provided above requests data for two Pubmed IDs, but I was using hard-coded values for demonstration purposes. I've now set the application to request data for 900 (previously 500) Pubmed IDs. I break up the returned file by article and write each partition--up to 900 of them--to a separate file. So to answer your question, yes, I write the files locally.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that might be a sensible approach to multithreading this is to separate the "network read" from the "disk write".  Multithreading the disk write likely *won't* result in performance benefit (possible exceptions for high-speed network storage), but the network requests *might* benefit.  So, instead of multi-threading your whole block, have something like this:

- Create a `Queue` for incoming `XmlDocument` objects
- Run one (or more) threads to handle the service requests and push objects into the `Queue` as the responses arrive
- Run a separate thread to monitor the `Queue` and write each item to disk

This way, no matter which side is the bottleneck, the whole process will run closer to an optimum speed.  You can then experiment with multiple threads on one or both sides of the `Queue` to see whether parallel requests/parallel disk IO will help.

Worth remembering that you have to ensure thread-safe access to the `Queue`, but that's fairly easily solved (the simplest way in .NET is to use the `Queue.Synchronized` method to get thread-safe access to an existing `Queue`).

Comment: That's a good idea--thanks for the suggestion! I am okay with the performance for now, but if the client wants better performance, I will refactor my solution according to your idea. I'm actually re-writing an application, and the speed of this operation is already faster than the previous program.